# Is it possible to increase precision of AWT graphics drawing operations?

Tags: java, graphics, precision, dpi

I am writing a java program to generate parabolic curves (essentially "curves" made of lots of straight lines to simulate the appearance of a curve, AKA straight line curves: see https://larc.unt.edu/ian/art/4ants/), and I am displaying it via a BufferedImage.

Disappointingly, the lines drawn by the drawLine method come out very blocky and staggered when at any sort of angle (see screenshot, particularly, top left and bottom right corners of the image, but also any of the angled lines in the middle).

Is there any way to get around this effect? Possibly by performing higher precision drawing operations?

[image]

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this, first, you can have a look at [Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html) or y can scale the image by a factor of 4 (obviously, you need to start start with an image 4x the size you need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Graphics2D object's rendering hints, using the [setRenderingHint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint-java.awt.RenderingHints.Key-java.lang.Object-) method, before drawing your lines.

Since you're drawing lines, there are three rendering hints you'll want to set:

- [KEY_ANTIALIASING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_ANTIALIASING)
- [KEY_RENDERING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_RENDERING)
- [KEY_STROKE_CONTROL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_STROKE_CONTROL)

Comment: Even that won't help if the line segments are too long. The OP may have to make the segments shorter.